# PHP's setcookie() function is not working. What's wrong?

Tags: php, setcookie

I really need some help here. I wrote this script to track my website's traffic. I ***was using*** cookies to help the server know when a client has visited a page once already for the day, which allowed me to track visitors by two (2) counters/categories: UNIQUE hits and "REFRESH" hits.

I store the information in directories named by date. For example, the file located at `www.example.com/counter/unique/2015/12/31/about` would store a number like 62, which would mean I got 62 unique hits to the `about.php` page on December 31st, 2015.

Each page calls the script `counter.php`. Everything seems to work fine, but both of my counters continue to read the same number, as if every hit is unique. I knew something was wrong when I saw the two sets of numbers, and I confirmed it by refreshing the index page several times. What it means is that the cookies are not being set. The PHP script in `counter.php` tests for the cookie to see if it has been set. I have been also checking the cookies from my browser settings and it shows no cookies. I refresh each page several times and re-check for the cookies several times, but still no luck!

What in the world is going on here?!? It was working before!

The following shows how each page calls the `counter.php` script:

`http://www.example.com/index.php`:

```
<?php
    include_once("log/counter.php");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

The following is my PHP code called `counter.php`:

`http://www.example.com/log/counter.php`

```
<?php

    // THIS LINE WAS NOT PART OF MY ORIGINAL SCRIPT
    ob_start();

    // THIS IS THE PAGE THAT IS CALLING THIS SCRIPT,
    // FOR EXAMPLE: ABOUT, INDEX, CONTACT, ETC.
    $page = basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], ".php");

    // THE DIRECTORY WHERE THIS SCRIPT IS LOCATED
    // RELEVANT TO THE CALLING PAGE
    $cwd = dirname(__FILE__) . "/counter/";

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
        // TIMEZONE FOR HOUSTON, TEXAS. THIS WAY, ALL
        // DATE & TIME INFO IS SET IN THAT TIMEZONE

    $currentYear = date("Y");   // EX: 2015
    $currentMonth = date("m");  // EX: 12
    $currentDay = date("d");    // EX: 31

    // THIS PREPARES THE DIRECTORY FOR TODAY'S DATE
    $today = $currentMonth."/".$currentDay."/".$currentYear;
    $current = $currentYear."/".$currentMonth."/".$currentDay."/";

    $currentHour = date("H");
    $currentMinute = date("i");
    $currentSecond = date("s");

    // THE FOLLOWING IS USED FOR THE COOKIE EXPIRATION PARAM

    $secondsRemaining = 60 - $currentSecond;
    $minutesRemaining = 59 - $currentMinute;
    $hoursRemaining = 23 - $currentHour;

    $totalSecondsRemaining = ($hoursRemaining * 60 * 60) + ($minutesRemaining * 60) + $secondsRemaining;

    if ($totalSecondsRemaining<=0) { $totalSecondsRemaining = 86400; }
        // 86400 SECONDS = 24 HOURS / 1 DAY

    $ucFile = $cwd . "unique/" . $current . $page;      // UNIQUE-HITS COUNTER
    $rcFile = $cwd . "refresh/" . $current . $page;     // REFRESH-HITS COUNTER

        // MAKE SURE ALL DIRECTORIES EXIST
        if (!file_exists($cwd."unique/")){
            mkdir($cwd."unique", 0755);
        }
        if (!file_exists($cwd."unique/".$currentYear)){
            mkdir($cwd."unique/".$currentYear, 0755);
        }
        if (!file_exists($cwd."unique/".$currentYear."/".$currentMonth)){
            mkdir($cwd."unique/".$currentYear."/".$currentMonth, 0755);
        }
        if (!file_exists($cwd."unique/".$currentYear."/".$currentMonth."/".$currentDay)){
            mkdir($cwd."unique/".$currentYear."/".$currentMonth."/".$currentDay, 0755);
        }
        if (!file_exists($cwd."refresh/")){
            mkdir($cwd."refresh", 0755);
        }
        if (!file_exists($cwd."refresh/".$currentYear)){
            mkdir($cwd."refresh/".$currentYear, 0755);
        }
        if (!file_exists($cwd."refresh/".$currentYear."/".$currentMonth)){
            mkdir($cwd."refresh/".$currentYear."/".$currentMonth, 0755);
        }
        if (!file_exists($cwd."refresh/".$currentYear."/".$currentMonth."/".$currentDay)){
            mkdir($cwd."refresh/".$currentYear."/".$currentMonth."/".$currentDay, 0755);
        }
        // ALL DIRECTORIES NOW EXIST. SO FAR, NO PROBLEMS!


    // UNIQUE COUNTER...
    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$page])){          // THIS ALWAYS GETS CALLED...
        if (file_exists($ucFile)){         // IF PAGE HAS BEEN COUNTED...
            $file = fopen($ucFile, "r+");  //  1. OPEN THE COUNTER FILE FOR PAGE
            $count = fgets($file);         //  2. GET THE CURRENT COUNT
            fclose($file);                 //  3. CLOSE THE FILE
            $file = fopen($ucFile, "w");   //  4. RE-OPEN FILE AND CLEAR IT
            fputs($file, $count+1);        //  5. REPLACE WITH CURRENT COUNT+1
        }
        if (!file_exists($ucFile)){        // IF THIS IS THE FIRST TIME TODAY...
            $file = fopen($ucFile, "w");   //  1. CREATE A COUNTER FOR THIS PAGE
            fputs($file, "1");             //  2. PUT 1 AS THE CURRENT COUNT
        }

        $works = setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining);
            // SET A COOKIE INDICATING THAT THIS PAGE HAS BEEN
            // VISITED ALREADY BY THIS GUEST.
    }


    // REFRESH COUNTER...
    if (file_exists($rcFile)){             // IF PAGE HAS BEEN COUNTED...
        $file = fopen($rcFile, "r+");      //  (REPEAT STEPS ABOVE, 1-5)
        $count = fgets($file);
        fclose($file);
        $file = fopen($rcFile, "w");
        fputs($file, $count+1);
    }
    if (!file_exists($rcFile)){
        $file = fopen($rcFile, "w");
        fputs($file, "1");
    }

    // AGAIN, NOT PART OF THE ORIGINAL SCRIPT.
    ob_end_flush();

    // ALWAYS RETURNS TRUE...
    echo "<!-- $works -->";
?>
```

I have tried everything I can think of to get this script working again. To the best of my knowledge, I never changed anything in the code; it just stopped working one day.

### So, what I've already checked so far is:

- I know there is **NO** output before the headers are sent.
- I know that PHP thinks the cookie is being set, because `setcookie()` returns true
- I know the cookie expiry date is set in the future.
- I know the expiry date is **NOT** larger than PHP's integer max-size

  - PHP Integer maximum value is about 32 bits, mine is no more than 5 characters
- I know that neither `www.example.com` nor simply `example.com` change the script's behavior

I have also tried the following:

```
setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining);
setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/");
setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/", "");

setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/", "mywebsite.com");
setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/", ".mywebsite.com");
setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/", "*.mywebsite.com");
setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/", "www.mywebsite.com");

setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/", "mywebsite.com", 0);
setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/", ".mywebsite.com", 0);
setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/", "*.mywebsite.com", 0);
setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/", "www.mywebsite.com", 0);

setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/", "mywebsite.com", false);
setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/", ".mywebsite.com", false);
setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/", "*.mywebsite.com", false);
setcookie($page, "Today is ".$today, $totalSecondsRemaining, "/", "www.mywebsite.com", false);
```

I isolated the problem to the PHP `setcookie()` function. Any help is really, really, greatly appreciated.

P.S.

Admittedly, I'm sure that it would be better to store this information in a MySQL Database, but I'll work on that once I get this problem fixed.

Comment: Are you actually setting the domain of the cookie to the domain the client 'sees' eg in the address bar?

Comment: Interesting asides regarding your database comment; storing the data in a file isn't just more difficult, it's also less reliable in that multiple simultaneous requests to the same link will almost certainly result in a lost count (ever know anybody that double-clicks all links in their browser? :) ), multiple servers won't be able to share their counts without some sort of network filesystem, and you can't easily snapshot the files for a point in time backup like you could the database.  Move towards a database for this quickly.  If you're not particularly fond of MySQL, may I suggest redis?

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled? Did you used the element inspector (on the network tab) to check the headers it is returning?

Comment: Are you sure you are on example.com? Are you perhaps working on localhost?

Comment: Don't forget that since cookies are saved in the browser, you can debug them by seeing what cookies your browser is storing.  And since they're set via http header, you can also see the cookies being sent via CURL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know the cookie expiry date is set in the future. I know the expiry
>   date is NOT larger than PHP's integer max-size PHP Integer maximum
>   value is about 32 bits, mine is no more than 5 characters

Uh, shouldn't the expiry time of a cookie be the number of seconds since epoch?  A 5 digit expiry date would be early January 2nd, 1970, so I don't think it's possible that your expiry date is both five characters or less, and also in the future.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php:

> This is a Unix timestamp so is in number of seconds since the epoch.
>   In other words, you'll most likely set this with the time() function
>   plus the number of seconds before you want it to expire

```
<?php
setcookie("hiworld", "true", time()+300);
?>
Hi, world!


curl -v danf.us/t.php
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7ff05180d000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7ff05180d000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to danf.us port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 66.191.143.117...
* Connected to danf.us (66.191.143.117) port 80 (#0)
> GET /t.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: danf.us
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server nginx/1.0.10 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.0.10
< Date: Fri, 02 Jan 2015 22:31:19 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=20
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13-pl0-gentoo
< Set-Cookie: hiworld=true; expires=Fri, 02-Jan-2015 22:36:19 GMT
<
Hi, world!
* Connection #0 to host danf.us left intact
```

Comment: That cookie will expire in 5 seconds

Comment: WOW! Oh my God, wow! Thank you so much Dan. I really can't believe that it was that simple. Everything is working again. I feel really dumb. I would have never figured that one out, at least not for another week or so. God! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it could help :P

5 _minutes_, @IsmaelMiguel.  The curl command I ran shows the date of the response (22:31:19) as well as the expiry date of the cookie (22:36:19).

Comment: I know the time is 5 minutes, but look at the time the cookie would expire and the time i posted the comment, you would see what I mean. To view the exact time, put your mouse on the comment's time.